# Mongrel on windows with rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongrel

I am deploying a rails 3 application on a windows machine and I wan to run the app on mongrel. I have installed mongrel manually (not through bundler). I didn't installed it through bundler because when I tried it, it errors

> Fetching source index for rubygems.org
>
> Could not reach rubygems repository
>
> http://rubygems.org Could not find gem mongrel <>=0, runtime in any of the source

So I downloaded .gem and installed.

But bundler still looks to fetch it from the repository.
Also, when I try to start server using "rails server mongrel" it says

> no such file to load - mongrel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup that works now for me. Here are the details:

- I installed Ruby 1.9.2 (ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32])
- I installed Mongrel through Gem (mongrel (1.2.0.pre2 x86-mingw32). It is necessary to take here the version 1.2.0.pre2, because the 1.1.x versions don't work with Rails 3.
- I added the line `gem 'mongrel', '1.2.0.pre2'` to the `Gemfile` in my Rails application.

I start the server with `rails s`, and it takes Mongrel as a default. See the similar question [LoadError running Mongrel with Rails3 and Ruby 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020309/problem-running-mongrel-with-rails3-and-ruby-1-9-2)

Hope the same setup works for you as well.