# Incompatible library creating new project with Aptana

Tags: aptana

I am a ruby and rails newbie, so my abilities to debug this are somewhat limited.

I have just added the eclipse plugin which failed, then downloaded the latest aptana studio which also failed. The failure was the same in both cases.

The nature of the failure is that when I create a new rails project, I get an error message about an incompatible library version "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/http11.so". The project is actually created, along with directories and files.

Google searches around this error message have only returned a couple of hits, which were not very helpful

I am wondering if this is about 64 bit libraries.

My software stack is:

- Windows 7 home premium 64bit
- Aptana RadRails, build: 2.0.5.1278709071
- Ruby1.9.3 gem 1.8.24

The console shows:

```
"4320"
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': incompatible library version - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/http11.so (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:17:in `const_get'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:17:in `block in get'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:17:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:17:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/commands/server.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/server:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:2:in `load'
    from -e:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It turns out this is a duplicate of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264798/mongrel-on-windows-with-rails3/4419008#4419008

Answer (score 1):

As noted above this is about a version of mongrel. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongrel_(web_server).

An important section is that is:

*After the original author Zed Shaw left the Ruby on Rails-scene[4] the releases of Mongrel stopped. The current release 1.1.5 is no longer able to install in Ruby versions higher than 1.9.2 which is recommended for Rails 3, the fix is to use the much older 1.2.0-pre2 release of Mongrel which isn't stable.*

As I am a naive ruby user, I thought I would go through the steps to make Aptana work.

```
1: run the command line interpreter, ensuring ruby is on the path
2: gem install -v 1.2.0-pre2 mongrel
3: Run aptana
4: open windows/preferences/rails
5: set the mongrel_rails path
```

I found my mongrel_rails path in <ruby_home>/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/bin/mongrel_rails

Hope this is helpful to others